# not able to find a file name in the directory using file name as a variable from a temporary file

Tags: bash, shell-script, csv

I have sample CSV file contains file names

```
f1
f2
f3
```

I want to search these file name in a directory, below is my code

```
while read f1
do
  ls -t | grep "$f1"
  if[ $? = 0 ]
  then
    echo file exists
  else 
    echo file does not exists
  fi

done<sample.csv
```

Somehow the `$f1` variable value is not substituting getting blank value.

Comment: I got your code to work, but you mention a CSV file, and I am not sure how you are parsing the CSV file prior to piping it into your code.

Comment: When you say your CSV file _contains_ the filenames, does it also contain _other data_ besides the filenames? Is the file a Unix text file, or was it created on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

The `ls` command is to list the contents of a directory, not to test whether a file exists or not.  Also `grep` is not generally suitable for working with filenames as filenames can technically contain newlines (and `grep` is a line-oriented tool, like most utilities that work on text files).

You also have a syntax error in the `if` test (missing space before `[`).

[According to comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587602/not-able-to-find-a-file-name-in-the-directory-using-file-name-as-a-variable-from/587611?noredirect=1#comment1095463_587611), the input file is also a DOS text file.  This means that each line read from the file will have an extra carriage-return character at the end, which in turn means that when a Unix script (or other Unix tool) reads the file, the carriage-return will be part of the data read.  In the case of this particular script, this in turn means that it's unlikely that a filename read from the file will be matched against an existing filename in the filesystem (carriage-returns are actually valid in Unix filenames, but very rarely or ever seen other than by mistake).

A DOS text file can be converted to a Unix text file format using the `dos2unix` conversion utility.

---

To test whether a file exists, just use the `-e` test with `[ ... ]`:

```
while IFS= read -r name; do
    if [ -e "$name" ]; then
        printf '%s exists\n' "$name"
    else
        printf '%s does not exist\n' "$name"
    fi
done <sample.csv
```

This assumes that the file `sample.csv` file contains a single filename or pathname per line.

Comment: thank you for response, but still am not able to achieve the desired output....still even the file contains in the directory where am executing ,the output shows does not exist. wht will be reason any idea??

Comment: Is the `sample.csv` a DOS text file (create on a Windows system), or does it have more data than just the filenames on each line?

Comment: sample.csv file created on linux server and it is in same directory where the script is executing and it does only file names in a single column without header.

Comment: @VijayKumar This means that either the files do not exist in the current directory, or the data in the CSV file contains invisible characters (spaces, tabs, or carriage-returns, or something else) that makes the filenames listed therein different from the filenames in the filesystem.

Comment: yes Kusal, you are correct at the end of the value there is a carriage-return r appended so the file name is not able to compare and getting filename does not exists.So what to do to avoid extra carriage return ?? please help.

Comment: @VijayKumar You convert the file to a Unix text file using the `dos2unix` tool. Also, please don't abbreviate people's names.

Comment: thank you . one more query :is this only way I can remove carriage return? any other way like while reading the csv  file can I avoid carriage return?

Comment: @VijayKumar If the file is a file containing Unix filenames, and if you're going to use this file with Unix tools, then it would be safest and sanest to just convert it to a Unix text file.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda ,it's worked after converting and it solved many problems in my script wit this change. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing semicolons/newlines in your code, preventing it from working at all. There is also a space missing after the if. Fixing this we get the one liner:

```
while read f1; do ls -t | grep "$f1"; if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo file exists; else echo file does not exists; fi; done
```

We could also use newlines where there are semicolons, and this might be a bit easier to read. (But I am keeping the code close to yours). This now works correctly. For example we can save it to `test.sh` and then it works as expected. E.g.

```
$ echo test.sh | bash test.sh
test.sh
file exists
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.But still the value where ls -t | grep "$f1" ---this $f1 value is not substituted correctly , when I do echo $f1 then it is showing correctly.When am using this in command la -t | grep "$f1" there it is not working.And the file sample.csv or txt what ever it is has one column and that column has values f1 f2 f3.

Comment: exact code:while read f1 ; do ls -t | grep "$f1" ;if [ $? = 0 ] ; then echo file exists; else echo no exists; fi; done<sample.txt/csv

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `zsh` script like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
# list of files to find on stdin or in file arguments, LF delimited
to_find=(${(f)"$(cat -- "$@")"})
in_current_dir=(*(ND))

# print files in both lists, LF delimited:
print -rC1 -- ${in_current_dir:*to_find}
```